# Grids и не корректные св-ва в браузере

Tags: css3, html5, grid, vue-cli, vue3

Есть такой код, который я копирую исходя из курса:

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
#app{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [container-start] 1fr [center-start] repeat(
  6, [col-start] minmax(min-content, 16.66667rem) [col-end])
  [center-end] 1fr [container-ends];
  grid-template-rows: min-content 100vh repeat(9, min-content);
}
</style>
```

Вопрос:
Задеплоить проект пока нет возможности - поэтому продемонстрировать могу скрин из браузера(на локалке) c предупреждениями:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем причина появления предупреждений в инспекторе браузеров?
Почему точно такие же св-ва дублируются после "некорректных" св-в c предупреждениями и данные дубликаты становятся корректными?
Как это исправить?
(подозреваю это может быть что то связанное с автогенерацией префиксов в разрезе vue.js проекта.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В чем причина появления предупреждений в инспекторе браузеров?

Слева - не предупреждение, а пояснение как работает разметка элемента.

> Почему точно такие же св-ва дублируются после "некорректных" св-в c предупреждениями и данные дубликаты становятся корректными?
> Как это исправить?

Никак, они не дублируются. Сборка префиксы добавила. Если браузер не будет поддерживать ваши стили, то он возьмет разметку с префиксами.